# PHP, Incosistent results with preg_replace (RegEx)

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a nudge in the right direction because the results I get from preg_replace don't make sense to me.

I've the following RegEx:

```
/([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})/([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})/([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,})/([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,})/([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,})\b
```

I've a file which consists of lines like this:

```
1: 

*/tdn/quota/plot_3/boot_tdd_8/Homes_Homes1/boot/bplsed/ruc001/No Files/pl1/Cookies/MMTException/container.rig,11/12/2017,29/11/2017,29/11/2017*

2:

*/vdm/quota/plot_1/boot_tdd_1/Homes_Homes2/.etc/nonrig_tile_edit.vids,07/08/2014,07/08/2014,07/08/2014*

3:

*/vdm/quota/plot_5/boot_tdd_3/Homes_Homes1/boot/int/rlt111/pl1/Cookies/container.rig,19/11/2019,13/11/2017,13/11/2017*
```

My goal is to only keep everything after the /Homes_Homes/ part.

I get the correct replacement for the first file path with my Regex:

```
*/boot/bplsed/ruc001/No Files/pl1/Cookies/MMTException/container.rig,11/12/2017,29/11/2017,29/11/2017*
```

The second file path is also correct:

```
*/.etc/nonrig_tile_edit.vids,07/08/2014,07/08/2014,07/08/2014*
```

However, for the last file path I get:

```
*/container.rig*
```

**instead of**

```
*/boot/int/rlt111/pl1/Cookies/container.rig,19/11/2019,13/11/2017,13/11/2017*
```

Why does preg_replace fail with the third file path?

Comment: Your pattern matches twice in the last string. https://regex101.com/r/PVMomx/1 You have to limit the replacement to 1 using the 4th parameter of [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) Or use an anchor `^` with a capturing group for the `*` and use `$1` in the replacement https://regex101.com/r/Vkblcb/1 If all the recurring parts in the pattern could be matched by `\w+`, you could also use `^\*\K(?:/\w+){5}` https://regex101.com/r/8AsJYG/1 See https://3v4l.org/kBe0F

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get that last result is because [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) will replace all the matches and in the last example string the pattern [matches twice](https://regex101.com/r/i7uAWw/1).

What you might do is set the 4th parameter `$limit` to 1 to do a single replacement.

Not all the character classes in your pattern match an underscore, but if it would be ok to do so, you might shorten the pattern using a quantifier `{5}`, and anchor `^` to assert the start of the srting and make use of \K to match and then forget the `*` at the start of the string.

```
^\*\K(?:/\w+){5}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cfKSIf/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/f74F1)

For example

```
$re = '~^\*\K(?:/\w+){5}~';
$strings = [
    "*/tdn/quota/plot_3/boot_tdd_8/Homes_Homes1/boot/bplsed/ruc001/No Files/pl1/Cookies/MMTException/container.rig,11/12/2017,29/11/2017,29/11/2017*",
    "*/vdm/quota/plot_1/boot_tdd_1/Homes_Homes2/.etc/nonrig_tile_edit.vids,07/08/2014,07/08/2014,07/08/2014*",
    "*/vdm/quota/plot_5/boot_tdd_3/Homes_Homes1/boot/int/rlt111/pl1/Cookies/container.rig,19/11/2019,13/11/2017,13/11/2017*"
];

foreach ($strings as $s) {
    echo preg_replace($re, '', $s) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
*/boot/bplsed/ruc001/No Files/pl1/Cookies/MMTException/container.rig,11/12/2017,29/11/2017,29/11/2017*
*/.etc/nonrig_tile_edit.vids,07/08/2014,07/08/2014,07/08/2014*
*/boot/int/rlt111/pl1/Cookies/container.rig,19/11/2019,13/11/2017,13/11/2017*
```

Comment: Thank you very, very much for your help and explanation. I understand now why my RegEx did not work properly.